# Clean way to calculate both group and overall statistics

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like like to calculate the `median` not only for different groups of my data, but also the `median` over all groups and store the result in a single `data.frame`. While accomplishing each of these tasks separately is easy, I have not found a clean way to do both at the same time.

Right now, what I'm doing is calculate both statistics separately; then join the results; then tidy the data if necessary. Here's an example of what this may look like if I wanted to know the median delay per day *and* per month:

```
library(dplyr)
library(hflights)

data(hflights)

# Calculate both statistics separately
per_day <- hflights %>% 
  group_by(Year, Month, DayofMonth) %>%
  summarise(Delay = mean(ArrDelay, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(Interval = "Daily")

per_month <- hflights %>% 
  group_by(Year, Month) %>%
  summarise(Delay = mean(ArrDelay, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(Interval = "Monthly", DayofMonth = NA)

# Join into a single data.frame
my_summary <- full_join(per_day, per_month,
                        by = c("Year", "Month", "DayofMonth", "Interval", "Delay"))

my_summary
# Source: local data frame [377 x 5]
# Groups: Year, Month
# 
# Year Month DayofMonth     Delay Interval
# 1  2011     1          1 10.067642    Daily
# 2  2011     1          2 10.509745    Daily
# 3  2011     1          3  6.038627    Daily
# 4  2011     1          4  7.970740    Daily
# 5  2011     1          5  4.172650    Daily
# 6  2011     1          6  6.069909    Daily
# 7  2011     1          7  3.907295    Daily
# 8  2011     1          8  3.070140    Daily
# 9  2011     1          9 17.254325    Daily
# 10 2011     1         10 11.040388    Daily
# ..  ...   ...        ...       ...      ...
```

Are there better ways to do this?

(Note that in many cases one could easily progressively roll up summaries as pointed out in the [Introduction to dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html). However, this doesn't work for statistics like `median`, `mean` etc.)

Comment: Instead of `summarise`, you could `mutate` and then `ungroup` and regroup before then next one. No way to test without example data.

Comment: Thanks,  Frank. I changed my code to work with the `hflights` dataset. Also, I appreciate your suggestion. But do you think this would be more efficient?

Comment: Hm, I don't know much about making `dplyr` code efficient; I use `data.table` for that. I was just thinking that perhaps you wanted to calculate both statistics in a single `%>%` chain.

Comment: Yes, a single `%>%` would be great, but I think the code is much more readable if the two steps are separated. Since it doesn't seem there's a "standard" way of doing what I would like to do, let me put it this way: I'd prefer consistent and efficient code over `dplyr` any time. So if `data.table` is a better choice for this task, I'd be happy to see your approach.

Comment: Okay, I've added a `data.table` way. It's pretty readable to my eye and probably quite a bit more efficient than computing separately and merging, certainly in terms of memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As a one-off table.** This is fairly straightforward in `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)

setDT(hflights)[,{
  mo_del <- mean(ArrDelay,na.rm=TRUE)
  .SD[,.(DailyDelay = mean(ArrDelay,na.rm=TRUE),MonthlyDelay = mo_del),by=DayofMonth]
},by=.(Year,Month)]
  #    Year Month DayofMonth DailyDelay MonthlyDelay
  # 1: 2011     1          1 10.0676417     4.926065
  # 2: 2011     1          2 10.5097451     4.926065
  # 3: 2011     1          3  6.0386266     4.926065
  # 4: 2011     1          4  7.9707401     4.926065
  # 5: 2011     1          5  4.1726496     4.926065
 # ---                                              
# 361: 2011    12         14  1.0293610     5.013244
# 362: 2011    12         17 -0.1049822     5.013244
# 363: 2011    12         24 -4.1457490     5.013244
# 364: 2011    12         25 -2.2976827     5.013244
# 365: 2011    12         31 46.4846491     5.013244
```

*How it works.* The basic syntax is `DT[i,j,by]`.

- With `by=.(Year,Month)`, all operations in `j` are done per "by group."
- We can nest another "by group" using the `data.table` of the current **S**ubset of **D**ata, `.SD`.
- To return columns in `j` we use `.(colname1=col1,colname2=col2,...)`.

---

**Creating new variables.** Alternately, we could create new variables in `hflights` using `:=` in `j`.

```
hflights[,DailyDelay   := mean(ArrDelay,na.rm=TRUE),.(Year,Month,DayofMonth)]
hflights[,MonthlyDelay := mean(ArrDelay,na.rm=TRUE),.(Year,Month)]
```

Then we can view the summary table:

```
hflights[,.GRP,.(Year,Month,DayofMonth,DailyDelay,MonthlyDelay)]
  #    Year Month DayofMonth DailyDelay MonthlyDelay .GRP
  # 1: 2011     1          1 10.0676417     4.926065    1
  # 2: 2011     1          2 10.5097451     4.926065    2
  # 3: 2011     1          3  6.0386266     4.926065    3
  # 4: 2011     1          4  7.9707401     4.926065    4
  # 5: 2011     1          5  4.1726496     4.926065    5
 # ---                                                   
# 361: 2011    12         14  1.0293610     5.013244  361
# 362: 2011    12         17 -0.1049822     5.013244  362
# 363: 2011    12         24 -4.1457490     5.013244  363
# 364: 2011    12         25 -2.2976827     5.013244  364
# 365: 2011    12         31 46.4846491     5.013244  365
```

(Something needed to be put in `j` here, so I used the "by group" code, `.GRP`.)